# webpack command not found after installing locally

Tags: npm, webpack

I am not able to run webpack command after installing locally in my project. `npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli` does not work and `npx webpack` does not work as well. From the [sources](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/npm-command-not-found-webpack) i've found, they tell me to install webpack locally or to use npx webpack but neither solution works.

The [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/) mention something about accessing webpack at `node_modules/.bin/webpack` but i'm not sure what they mean by that.

Please don't tell me to install globally, as the docs advise against it.

node version 20.4.0 & npm version 9.7.2

```bash
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

error after installing locally

```bash
webpack-starter|⇒ npm run start

> webpack-starter@1.0.0 start
> webpack

sh: webpack: command not found
```

error after trying npx webpack

```bash
webpack-starter|⇒ npx webpack
CLI for webpack must be installed.
  webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)

We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D webpack-cli".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): yes
Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'npm install -D webpack-cli')...

up to date, audited 1 package in 386ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/brados/.npm/_npx/89d6e678e21f2dae/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:125:19)
    at runCli (/Users/brados/.npm/_npx/89d6e678e21f2dae/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:78:26)
    at /Users/brados/.npm/_npx/89d6e678e21f2dae/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:178:5
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/brados/.npm/_npx/89d6e678e21f2dae/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Blockquote The docs mention something about accessing webpack at node_modules/.bin/webpack but i'm not sure what they mean by that.

it means you need to replace every webpack command with this.
for example:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Meanwhile, you should be able to run `node_modules/.bin/webpack --version` to check the version number.